# cant select the different element in md-select list in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium

below is the html for md-select list i can click on it but when it expands i cant select the different element

```html
<div class="steps ng-scope" ng-transclude="" ng-if="indicatorsPosition === 'top'">
<section class="step ng-scope ng-isolate-scope current" ng-transclude="" ng-class="{current: selected, done: completed}" ng-show="selected" canexit="exitValidation" wz-title="Select Vendor" aria-hidden="false">
<h2 class="ng-scope">Select your Vendor</h2>
<div class="ui-wizard-content ng-scope">
<md-input-container class="md-block flex-gt-sm md-input-has-value" flex-gt-sm="" data-ng-disabled="lockMode=='Y'" aria-disabled="false">
<label class="" for="select_155">Vendor</label>
<!-- Example with a straight select <select data-ng-model="activeData.selectedVendor" ng-options="vendor as vendor.name for vendor in vendors track by vendor.id"> <select> -->
<md-select id="select_155" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" ng-model-options="{trackBy:'$value.SUPPLIER_BUSINESS_ID'}" data-ng-model="activeData.selectedVendor" data-ng-disabled="lockMode=='Y'" style="font-size: 150%;" tabindex="0" aria-label="Select your vendor: DSI MFG " md-labeled-by-tooltip="md-tooltip-154" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-owns="select_container_156" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false">
<md-select-value id="select_value_label_153" class="md-select-value">
<span>
<span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"/>
</md-select-value>
</md-select>
```

Below is the html when we click on the md-select list

---

```html
<div id="select_container_156" class="md-select-menu-container md-active md-clickable" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; left: 529px; top: 259px; min-width: 1068.67px; font-size: 21px;">
<md-select-menu class="_md" style="transform-origin: 518.333px 32px 0px;">
<md-content class="_md">
<!-- ngRepeat: vendor in vendors -->
<md-option id="select_option_178" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" data-ng-value="vendor" data-ng-repeat="vendor in vendors" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-selected="true" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]" selected="selected">
<div class="md-text ng-binding">                              DSI MFG                            </div>
<div class="md-ripple-container" style=""/>
</md-option>
<!-- end ngRepeat: vendor in vendors -->
<md-option id="select_option_179" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" data-ng-value="vendor" data-ng-repeat="vendor in vendors" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
<div class="md-text ng-binding">                              Phase 1 TR1                            </div>
</md-option>
<!-- end ngRepeat: vendor in vendors -->
<md-option id="select_option_180" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" data-ng-value="vendor" data-ng-repeat="vendor in vendors" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
<div class="md-text ng-binding">                              GREEN MARKET                            </div>
</md-option>
<!-- end ngRepeat: vendor in vendors -->
<md-option id="select_option_181" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" data-ng-value="vendor" data-ng-repeat="vendor in vendors" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
<div class="md-text ng-binding">                              KRUTHIKA STORE                            </div>
</md-option>
<!-- end ngRepeat: vendor in vendors -->
</md-content>
</md-select-menu>
```

Comment: Can you share your code trials?

Comment: List<WebElement> allelemts = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//md-select-value/span[1]/div"));
     for(WebElement ele: allelemts){

       driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//md-select-value/span[1]/div")).click();

       JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
       executor.executeScript("arguments[1].click();", ele);

     } above is the code i have used and below is the error i am getting                                                 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Comment: Can you share screenshot of part of UI for above html?

Comment: @PuneethR Can you sum up your exact manual steps which you are trying to Automate?

Comment: thank you guys. I found the solution we can select the element by using xpath.